# rails gemfile 'block in setup'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, annotate, gemfile

I'm using rails 3.1 and have specified to get the latest annotate gem from github in my gemfile

```
gem 'annotate', "~> 2.4.1beta", :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
```

I've run bundle install but when I run annotate to annotate my models I get the error...

```
`block in setup': You have already activated annotate 2.4.0, but your Gemfile requires annotate 2.4.1.beta1. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I'm still to get my head around how gems are updated etc so any advise on how to resolve this would be great. I've tried bundle exec but I get a 'wrong number of arguments' error.

Thanks!
Mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what is your annotate command but you should try

```
prompt> bundle exec {your annotate command with its args}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks... but still if I just run 'annotate' without bundle exec it still comes up with the error.. is there no way to fix this so I don't have to run 'bundle exec annotate' every time?

Comment: If you run 'annotate' individually it will run regardless gems dependency specification in your gemfile. Using 'bundle exec' will execute your desired command in the correct project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

Try to uninstall rack with

```
gem uninstall annotate
```

and when ask you about your annotate version, select `2.4.0`

and run

```
bundle install
```